# Sharepoint Sync with AD

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, user-accounts, sync

I have an internal SharePoint site running SharePoint Services 3.0. It was built by a web developer who no longer works here.

I need to force a synchronization between the SharePoint database and Active Directory to resolve a user account issue.

How can I force a sync between Sharepoint Services 3.0 and Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can carry out the following things and test!

1.In Central Admin -> System Setting -> Manage Services on server check for following service have status = started.

- User profile Service
- User profile Sync Service

  2. In Central Admin -> Application Management -> Manage Service Applications
     Select User Profile Service Application. Check for the following 
     Configure Synchronization Connection setting is correct.
     start the Profile synchronization by clicking the link.